# Не работает класс Square

Tags: java

Есть код примера для коллизий(самостоятельный,единственный класс)-
Square.java

```
package things;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//класс-квадрат
final class Square {
    public int x, y, w, h;

    Square() {
    }

    Square(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        w = _w;
        h = _h;
    }

    //пересечение квадратов
    public static boolean isIntersect(Square a, Square b) {
        return ((a.x < (b.x + b.w)) &&
                (b.x < (a.x + a.w)) &&
                (a.y < (b.y + b.h)) &&
                (b.y < (a.y + a.h)));
    }

    //пересечение квадратов с выталкиванием
    public static boolean isLockIntersect(Square a, Square b) {
        if (!isIntersect(a, b))
            return false;
        int x0 = b.x - (a.x - b.w);
        int y0 = b.y - (a.y - b.h);
        int x1 = (a.x + a.w) - b.x;
        int y1 = (a.y + a.h) - b.y;
        if (x1 < x0)
            x0 = -x1;
        if (y1 < y0)
            y0 = -y1;

        if (Math.abs(x0) < Math.abs(y0))
            a.x += x0;
        else if (Math.abs(x0) > Math.abs(y0))
            a.y += y0;
        else {
            a.x += x0;
            a.y += y0;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

//для примера
final class Form extends JFrame {
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private BufferedImage dimg = null;
    private Graphics hdc = null;
    private Square[] arr = null;
    private Square square = null;

    Form() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Пример работы пересечений");
        setSize(640, 480);
        Dimension ssize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setLocation((ssize.width - getWidth()) / 2,
                (ssize.height - getHeight()) / 2);

        dimg = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        hdc = dimg.getGraphics();

        square = new Square();
        square.w = 50;
        square.h = 100;
        square.x = (getWidth() - square.w) / 2;
        square.y = getHeight() - square.h * 2;

        arr = new Square[3];
        arr[0] = new Square(90, 250, 100, 30);
        arr[1] = new Square(430, 150, 90, 100);
        arr[2] = new Square(250, 120, 50, 30);

        ActionListener tevent = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Form.this.repaint();
            }
        };
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(10, tevent);
        timer.start();

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                Form.this.on_keyPress(e);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics dc) {
        hdc.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        hdc.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        hdc.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        hdc.fillRect(square.x, square.y, square.w, square.h);

        hdc.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Square q : arr) {
            hdc.fillRect(q.x, q.y, q.w, q.h);
        }
        dc.drawImage(dimg, 0, 0, null);
    }

    //управление пользователем синим квадратом
    void on_keyPress(KeyEvent e) {
        int vel = 3;
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                square.x -= vel;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                square.x += vel;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                square.y -= vel;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                square.y += vel;
                break;
        }

        //коллизия с пнями
        for (Square s : arr) {
            Square.isLockIntersect(square, s);
        }
    }
}


class BattleSquare {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Почему тут работают столкновения а у меня нет? и как хотя бы проверить на столкновения.
Вот мой код Game.java

```
package things;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
final public class Game {

    public int x, y, w, h;
    Game() {
    }
    Game(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        w = _w;
        h = _h;
    }
    public static boolean isIntersect(Game a, Game b) {
        return ((a.x < (b.x + b.w)) &&
                (b.x < (a.x + a.w)) &&
                (a.y < (b.y + b.h)) &&
                (b.y < (a.y + a.h)));
    }
    public static boolean isLockIntersect(Game a, Game b) {
        if (!isIntersect(a, b)){
            return false;
        }
        int x0 = b.x - (a.x - b.w);
        int y0 = b.y - (a.y - b.h);
        int x1 = (a.x + a.w) - b.x;
        int y1 = (a.y + a.h) - b.y;
        if (x1 < x0)
            x0 = -x1;
        if (y1 < y0)
            y0 = -y1;

        if (Math.abs(x0) < Math.abs(y0))
            a.x += x0;
        else if (Math.abs(x0) > Math.abs(y0))
            a.y += y0;
        else {
            a.x += x0;
            a.y += y0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void outt(Game a,Game b){
        if (!isIntersect(a, b)){
            System.out.println("Столкновение");
        }
    }
}
class Game1 extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    static int vert = sSize.height;
    static int hor = sSize.width;
    private boolean running;
    public static int WIDTH = vert;
    public static int HEIGHT = hor;
    public static String NAME = "GAME OF YEAR";
    private static float xx = 0f;
    private static float yy = 0f;
    private boolean leftPressed = false;
    private boolean rightPressed = false;
    private boolean upPressed = false;
    private boolean downPressed = false;
    private boolean sprint = false;
    float speed = 0f;
    Image img = (new ImageIcon(Game1.class.getResource("bcg.png"))).getImage();
    Image tree = (new ImageIcon(Game1.class.getResource("tree.png"))).getImage();
    public static Sprite heroUP;
    public static Sprite heroDown;
    public static Sprite sprt;
    public static Sprite heroRight;
    public static Sprite heroleft;
    private static int x1;
    private static int y1;
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("gg.gif"));



    public void start() {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long delta;

        init();

        while (running) {

            delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime;
            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            render();
            update(delta);
        }
    }




    public void init() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyInputHandler());
        heroUP = getSprite("things/man-up.png");
        heroDown = getSprite("things/man-down.png");
        heroleft = getSprite("things/man-left.png");
        heroRight = getSprite("things/man-right.png");
        sprt = getSprite("things/gg.png");


    }



    public void painter(Graphics g)
    {

        g.drawImage(img, 0,0,null);

    }
    static int posx;
    static int posy;
    static int sw;
    static int sh;
    int pox;
    int poy;
    public void tree(Graphics g)
    {
        float h = tree.getHeight(null);
        float w = tree.getWidth(null);
        posx=400;
        posy=200;
        sw= 100;
        sh=100;
        pox = posx+(int)w/2-(sw/2)-20;
        poy = (int)h;

        g.drawImage(tree, posx, posy,null);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Game q : arr) {
            g.fillRect(q.x, q.y, q.w, q.h);
        }
    }
    static int px;
    static int py;
    static int pwc;
    static int phc;
    public static void  player(Graphics g){

        phc = 50;
        pwc = 50;
        px = (int)xx+6;
        py = (int)yy+35+90;
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(px,py,phc,pwc);
    }
    private Game[] arr = null;
    private Game squaree = null;
    public void collision(){
        squaree = new Game();
        squaree.x=px;
        squaree.y=py;
        squaree.w=pwc;
        squaree.h=phc;
        arr = new Game[3];
        arr[0] = new Game (pox,poy,sw,sh);
        arr[1] = new Game(430, 150, 90, 100);
        arr[2] = new Game(250, 120, 50, 30);
    }
    public void render() {
        collision();
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(2);
            requestFocus();
            return;
        }


        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics(); //ïîëó÷àåì Graphics èç ñîçäàííîé íàìè BufferStrategy
        g.setColor(Color.black); //âûáðàòü öâåò
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); //çàïîëíèòü ïðÿìîóãîëüíèê
        painter(g);



        if(downPressed==true){
            heroDown.draw(g, x1, y1);
        }
        else if(rightPressed==true) {
            heroRight.draw(g, x1, y1);
        }
        else if(leftPressed==true) {
            heroleft.draw(g, x1, y1);
        }
        else if(upPressed==true) {
            heroUP.draw(g, x1, y1);
        }
        else {
            heroDown.draw(g, x1, y1);
        }
        tree(g);
        sprt.map(g,0,0);
        player(g);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show(); //ïîêàçàò
    }

    public void update(long delta) {

        squaree.x=(int)xx;
        squaree.y=(int)yy;
        if(sprint==true){
            speed=0.3f;
        }
        else {
            speed=0;
        }

        if (leftPressed == true) {
            xx = xx - 0.5f;
            xx = xx -speed;
        }
        if (rightPressed == true) {
            xx+=0.5f;
            xx=xx+speed;
        }
        if (upPressed == true) {
            yy= yy -0.5f;
            yy=yy-speed;
        }
        if (downPressed == true) {
            yy= yy +0.5f;
            yy=yy+speed;
        }
    }

    public Sprite getSprite(String path) {
        BufferedImage sourceImage = null;

        try {
            URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
            sourceImage = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(sourceImage.getSource()));

        return sprite;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game1 game = new Game1();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(hor, vert));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(Game1.NAME);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        game.start();

    }
    private class KeyInputHandler extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                leftPressed = true;
                System.out.println("left");
                System.out.println(xx);
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                rightPressed = true;
                System.out.println("right");
                System.out.println(xx);
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                upPressed = true;
                System.out.println("up");
                System.out.println(yy);
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                downPressed = true;
                System.out.println("down");
                System.out.println(yy);
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
                sprint = true;

            }
            for (Game s : arr) {
                Game.isLockIntersect(squaree, s);
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                leftPressed = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                rightPressed = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                upPressed = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                downPressed = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
                sprint = false;

            }

        }
    }
}
class BattleSquare1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game1 form1 = new Game1();
        form1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Мучался над тем чтоб запустилось 4 дня и оно не работает!

Comment: Что в результате? Что значит не работает? Ошибка или работает не так, как задумывалось?

Comment: Игра запускается,можно передвигаться но выталкивания не происходит,и я незнаю как это отладить